# GITHUB - Problemas para associar repositório local em relação ao repositório remoto

Tags: github

Estou iniciando em programação e iremos utilizar o git/github, estou criando o primeiro projeto; segui os passos : iniciei um repositório ( git init ); associei o repositório local ao remoto
(git remote add origin https://github.com/jlamancio/aula1-github.git; no momento de atualizar o repositório local ao remoto ( git pull origin master) está retornando o seguinte erro:  - fatal: couldn't find remote ref master. Podem me ajudar ?

Comment: Quando você cria o repositório local, a branch padrão é `master`; quando você cria no GitHub é a branch `main` (pois o GitHub alterou esse padrão tempos atrás). Você precisa definir o mesmo nome nas branchs.

Answer (score -1):

No seu repositório local a branch padrão é a master. Porém no GitHub a branch padrão agora é a branch main. Para corrigir o erro que você está tendo você precisa renomear a sua branch local de master para main usando o comando:

```
git branch -m master main
```

Então quando for enviar para o repositório remoto você também atualiza a branch que quer que seja enviada:

```
 git pull origin main
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Letícia, tudo isso pra mim é novo , então apanho bastante ainda !

Answer (score -1):

Verifique o nome da branch que vc está usando com o comando:

```
git branch
```

Em seguida vc pode dar o git pull origin com a respectiva branch selecionada, mas no seu caso acredito que vc pode dar um git pull sem passar parametros, pois por padrão ele sincroniza tudo com a master/main

Caso vc queira alterar o nome da branch que está selecionada utilize o comando:

```
git branch -m novo-nome
```

Caso queira criar uma nova branch utilize:

```
git checkout -b nova-branch
```

O comando acima cria a branch e seleciona a branch criada, caso queira apenas criar uma branch sem selecioná-la utilize:

```
git checkout nova-branch
```